# Allow single login per account - CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I want to ensure that the user is logged in only one device at any given point of time. Just like the banks do it. How can this be ensured and implemented in the CouchDB Authentication suite?

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood correctly, this cannot be achieved out-of-the-box with CouchDB.  In CouchDB version 2.0, the only authentication mechanisms supported are:

1. HTTP basic authentication
2. cookies

#### Basic authentication

As each request is authenticated separately with this scheme, it's meaningless to think of a user as being "logged in".

#### Cookies

CouchDB does not keep track of cookies that it has issued.  This means that it has no knowledge of open/active sessions that exist.  For this reason, it would have no way of restricting the number of active sessions for a particular user.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this would be to use a proxy server in front of CouchDB, along with [proxy authentication](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/server/authn.html#proxy-authentication).  It would be the responsibility of your proxy server to enforce whatever limits you desire.